# Need SQLite3 APIS for iPhone

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I need to add some Database stuff in my iPhone application. i know how to use Database methods manually. But i want to prebuilt APIs which allows me to create tables, insert, delete and update records according to my tables. So is there any kind of prebuilt APIS for sqlite3 in Iphone. Please guide me if there is any.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb , it's  really easy to use

Comment: hey nice one. Can u guide me with some code how to create DB File and open it and then execute query for table creation ? please  I am new in iPhone

Comment: Check this one, it should do a better job than a quick sample code I can write for you. http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/11/04/simple-sqlite-database-interaction-using-fmdb/